# Install Linux (Kali) to an external HDD

Tags: linux, hard-drive, usb, external-hard-drive

i wanted to create a mobile "programming-environment" using an **external HDD**, I definitely want to use Kali Linux without a vm, so it needs to be bootable on that hard drive. But the problem is, that my main machine is a 2019 MacBook Pro with only two Thunderboldt 3 inputs, the bad thing about it is that my flash drive **don't** support usb-c, so I have no chance to use it. My thoughts were that its maybe possible to flash the Linux ISO file *directly to a created partition* on my HDD. I googled all day long but didn't find a clear answer. I would appreciate it when you answer on that question if you maybe know how it could work, if its even possible.

Answer (score 0):

First off, I would strongly reccomend against using Kali for this purpose.  Kali is good for pentesting, but you will experience problems if you just try to use it as a general programming environment.  Kali also reccomends against installing it; they reccomend just running the live image with persistence.

Second, it is easier to just buy a USB C flash drive or USB C to USB B adapter.  That is also probably a better long term strategy as you'll likely need it for sometging later, anyway.

That being said, I believe what you're describing is dual booting Kali.  That normally requires burning an installation medium, then booting from the medium and running the installer.  Since you want to do it without another installation medium, one option is to burn the image to another patition on your hard drive, then boot into that, then install it to another partition.  This can be done with UNetbootin, which will burn the image and install a bootlader which allows you to actually boot it.  Once installed, you can then delete the installation partition and update the bootloader.  This method is doable, but again, I would reccomend just getting another flash drive and making things easier.